# How do I fix the error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee0761ed8)"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, moya, yelp-fusion-api

I am using swift to build an app in Xcode. it builds fine, but when it runs, it stops and gives me an error on the line a declare my delegate(this line: "weak var delegate: LocationActions?") in LocationService.swift. Here is the error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee0761ed8)

I tried plenty of things but couldn't figure it out. can anyone help me solve this problem? If you can, thank you so much here is my code:

**LocationService.swift**

```
import CoreData
import Moya
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire


protocol LocationActions: class {
func didChangeLocationAuthorizationRD()
}
class LocationService:NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

weak var delegate: LocationActions?

var newLocation: ((Result<CLLocation>) -> Void)?
let locationManager: CLLocationManager
lazy var latitude = Double(locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 100000.00)
lazy var longitude = Double(locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 100000.00)
lazy var tempLatitude = Double(locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 100000.00)
   let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
   var lat = 0.0
   var long = 0.0
let dataSource = DataSource()


func requestLocationAuthorization() {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
func getLocation() {
    locationManager.requestLocation()
}

var didChangeStatus: ((Bool) -> Void)?
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
        didChangeStatus?(false)

    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        didChangeStatus?(true)
        self.delegate?.didChangeLocationAuthorizationRD()


    }
}


override init() {
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    super.init()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self

}



func setup(latOrLong : String) -> Double {

       self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

       if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() {
           self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
       }
    if latOrLong == "lat" {
               return self.latitude
           }else if latOrLong == "long" {
               return self.longitude
           } else {
               print("error enter either lat or long in the paramaters for the function setup located in LocationServices.swift")
        return 3.141592653
           }
   }
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Moya
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


var theViewModels = [RestrauntListViewModel]()
let locationService = LocationService()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    let locationServices = LocationService()
    let lat = locationServices.setup(latOrLong: "lat")
    let long = locationServices.setup(latOrLong: "long")
    locationServices.lat = lat
    locationServices.long = long

    let dataSource = DataSource()
    loadBusinesses(lat: lat, long: long)
    print("this is the view models in appDelegate: \(theViewModels)")


    locationService.didChangeStatus = { [weak self] success in
        if success {
            self?.locationService.getLocation()
        }
    }

    locationService.newLocation = { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let location):
            self?.loadBusinesses(lat: location.coordinate.latitude, long: location.coordinate.longitude)
        case .failure(let error):
            assertionFailure("Error getting the users location \(error)")
        }
    }

    locationService.delegate = self
    return true
}
func loadBusinesses (lat: Double, long: Double) {

           var contentView = ContentView()
           let service = MoyaProvider<YelpService.BusinessProvider>()
           let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

           let restrauntView = RestrauntView()
        let appDelegate = AppDelegate()
           print("The latitude of u is \(lat) and the long of you is \(long)")


           if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
                   case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                       print("No access")

                   contentView.tapToDecideText = "Please allow us to use your location in settings so that we can show you restraunts near by. Once you have let us use your location please restart the application."
                   case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                       print("Access")

                                  service.request(.search(lat: lat, long: long)) { (result) in
                                       switch result{
                                       case.success(let response):
                                           print("yaya")
                                           let root = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: response.data)
                                           let viewModels = root?.businesses.compactMap(RestrauntListViewModel.init)
                                           let dataSource = DataSource()
                                           dataSource.arrayOfImages.removeAll()



                                           for image in viewModels! {

                                                       Alamofire.request(image.imageURL).responseImage { response in
                                                           if let image = response.result.value {
                                                               print("image downloadedline 59 appdelegate")
                                                               dataSource.arrayOfImages.append(image)
                                                               print(dataSource.arrayOfImages)
                                                           } else {
                                                               print("ERROR: image does not = response.result.value")
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                   }

                                           self.theViewModels = (root?.businesses.compactMap(RestrauntListViewModel.init))!


                                           print(" restrauntView.theViewModels is here \(restrauntView.theViewModels)")

                                           print("the constant theViewModels in the appdelegate has \(appDelegate.theViewModels.count) values")

                                       case .failure(let error):
                                           print("Error: \(error)")
                                       }
                   }

                   @unknown default:
                   break
               }



               } else {
                   print("Location services are not enabled")
           }


       }




// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Actrual_Food_Circle")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

}

extension AppDelegate: LocationActions{
func didChangeLocationAuthorizationRD() {
    locationService.requestLocationAuthorization()
}
}
```

Comment: Are you running on device? if yes, so which device?

Comment: I'm running it on a iPhone 11 pro simulator.

Comment: Please try running this on device.

Comment: It worked! Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You hide member variable with local one which later released

```
let locationService = LocationService()        // 1st

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    let locationServices = LocationService()  // 2nd <<< remove this line
```

Answer (score 2):

This means you are accessing something that is not the exact type of component. So double-check your all variables and classes some variables might be the wrong Inheritance.

Example:
You are working with a `CustomImageView` but in your reference variable its extends `UIImageVIew`